# Is there a way to change the Time of life in a laracast flash?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, flash-message

I want to change the time a flash notification is shown.

I have a working laracast flash and that is fine, but the flash coveres about 1/4 of the screen, so I only want it forabout 2sek and not like 10sek as it is now. I don't know where to start. Is there such a function?

This is the flash

```
if ( ! function_exists('flash')) {

    /**
     * Arrange for a flash message.
     *
     * @param  string|null $message
     * @param  string      $level
     * @return \Laracasts\Flash\FlashNotifier
     */
    function flash($message = null, $level = 'info')
    {
        $notifier = app('flash');

        if ( ! is_null($message)) {
            return $notifier->message($message, $level);
        }

        return $notifier;
    } 

}
```

This is where it is called

```
if ($cartItem->save()) {
            flash(trans( 'alerts.cart_added'), 'success')->important();

return back();
```

Comment: I think this is rather related to bootstrap, so you'd have to twerk the .js file of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple example in the GitHub page of the package [Hiding Flash Message](https://github.com/laracasts/flash#hiding-flash-messages)

From the document,

Write a simple bit of JavaScript. For example, using jQuery, you might add the following snippet just before the closing  tag.

`<script>
$('div.alert').not('.alert-important').delay(3000).fadeOut(350);
</script>`

This will find any alerts - excluding the important ones, which should remain until manually closed by the user - wait three seconds, and then fade them out.

So for your case you just need to only target the specific important class
like:

(if you are using jQuery)

`$('.alert-important').delay(3000).fadeOut(350);`